# Copy rows from multiple sheets to another sequentially

Tags: excel, vba, copy, report

I am trying to write a script that takes all the rows (after the header row), and copies them sequentially into the first tab. I also have 10 tabs i would like it to do this for, and sequentially paste them into the first tab (basically pull everything from the other sheets, and put it into the first sheet like a big master sheet or report)

I tried this, but its not working

```
Sub Report()

page = 2
row = 1
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim pae As Integer
Dim rw As Integer
Dim WSheet(1 To 12) As Worksheet

lastRow = Worksheets(page).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).rw

    While (pge <= 12)
            While (rw <= lastRow)
        rw = rw + 1
        ws1.Rows(row).EntireRow.Copy WSheet(pge).Range("A" & lastRow)
            Wend
        pge = pge + 1
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

I was trying to get it to count how many rows have data, and then copy all of those rows to the first sheet before moving on to the next sheet,

It seems to skip over where i declare the variables, and then errors out on the lastrow assignment

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: looks like a typo? `.End(xlUp).Row` (`Row`, not `rw`) - you need the `Row` property, not the `rw` variable there.

Comment: You're also using rw as a counter, but using row to select the row.  You will also need to reset lastrow each page loop.  You're also using page and pge.

Comment: Not related: You should always use the `Long` variable type for rows, since `Integers` can only hold 32,767 rows - and you aren't even using the `pae` variable. (so in short, lots of typos it seems)

Comment: Please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to enforce variable declaration, this also helps you to catch typo most of the time.

Comment: `ws1` is not declared, not set. Why copying each row and not `UsedRange` (except the first row) at once? `WSheet` is declared **but not loaded**. The same observation regarding `Long` instead of `Integer` for all declarations. In VBA it is not any benefit to declare it as `Integer`. Only the risk to exceed its maximum limit... `lastRow` calculated outside the loop returns only the situation in the second sheet. Do all of the others have the same number of rows?

Comment: Them, there are `pge`, `page`, `pae` variables and use `pge` after initialization of `page` (not declared)... Similar issue for `row` and `rw`.

Comment: have you tried the build-in Excel feature PowerQuery? Easier as writing a VBA. e.g. looking for [PowerQuery merge tabs](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/consolidate-multiple-excel-sheets-using-power-query/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub ReportMaster()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastER As Long, lastCol As Long

 Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)

 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
        lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        lastCol = ws.cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastER = ws1.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'last empty row
        ws.Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy ws1.Range("A" & lastER)
    End If
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: @user1787114 Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: It worked! I changed a1 to b2 so it skipped the headers, and then neted the original if statement inside another to check if the sheet was blank (it was pulled the headers on the blank sheets), and it all seems golden!